# Which is the more reliable method for reporting classification results in deep learning?

Tags: classification, deep-learning, unbalanced-classes, model-comparison

I have two methods to compare, the one which reports weighted F1-score with imbalanced data and, the one which reports better F1-score with balanced data.
I am confused as to which method's performance should be considered good if only F1-scores are provided.

> 1. Unbalanced data - weighted F1-score = 0.75
> 2. Balanced data - F1- score = 0.82

The algorithms use the same dataset and have four classes. The class-wise F1- score performance in each case, respectively is mentioned below:

> [image]
>
> [image: Blockquote]

What can be the logical explanation of class-wise performance difference between the two approaches when overall performance is better for method number 2?
For unbalanced data, the number of samples in each class is 7722, 5712, 6970, 2039. After balancing, the number of samples becomes 7722, 7275, 6970, 7804.